# I can't solve the Counting Cards problem on freeCodeCamp

Tags: javascript

This is the freeCodeCamp Counting Cards activity.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards

My solution was

```
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (card = 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6) {
    count + 1;
    } else if (card = 7 || 8 || 9) {
    return;
    } else if (card = 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A")
    count - 1;
}
if (count > 0) {
  return count + " " + "Bet";
} else if {
 return count + " " + "Hold";
}
  // Only change code above this line
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

I checked the solution and it seemed similar. Why didn't it work?

Comment: `card = 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6` won't do what you expect. Firstly `=` is assignment, not equality. Secondly, `card == 2 || 3` does not compare `card` and against 2 or 3. Thirdly, please don't tag Java when you mean JavaScript.

Comment: You also need to actually increment/ decrement `count` by using `count++` or `count--` because `count + 1` does not assign count the new value.

Answer (score 1):

A Few Modifications were necessary for this code to work.

1. `=` is assignment operator while `==` is comparing operator.
2. `else if` can be replaced with just `else` if there is no condition.
3. the third `else if (card = 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A")` didnt have closing or opening brackets.
4. avoid using `return` at `else if (card == 7 || 8 || 9) {` and instead use `count += 0`
5. You need too add a condition for `||` Or operator like this `card == 7 || card == 8` and not like `card == 7 || 8`
6. Use `count++` and `count--` instead of `count + 1` and `count - 1`
   After all these changes the below code works fine.

```js
let count = 0;
function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (card == 2 || card == 3 || card == 4 || card == 5 || card == 6) {
    count++;
    } else if (card == 7 || card == 8 || card == 9) {
    count += 0;
    } else if (card == 10|| card == "J"|| card == "Q"|| card == "K"|| card == "A"){
    count--;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      return count + " " + "Bet";
    } else {
      return count + " " + "Hold";
    }
}
cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Answer (score 1):

**=** is used to assign a value and not to make comparison. In javascript we use **==** or **===** to make comparison, and also `count - 1` will not update count. use `count = count - 1` or `count++`

```
let count = 0;    
function cc(card) {
      // Only change code below this line
      if ( card >= 2 && card <= 6) {
        count = count + 1;
        } else if (card >= 7 && card <= 9) {
        return;
        } else if (card === 10 || card === "J" ||  card ===  "Q" || card ===  "K" || card ===  "A")
        count = count - 1;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
      return count + " " + "Bet";
    } else if {
     return count + " " + "Hold";
    }
      // Only change code above this line
    }
    
    cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: hi there! in your solution the next else if statement is using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Both your `else if`s are incorrect

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues with your code.

#### Wrong `if` condition

Your `if` condition `card = 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6` does not work like you think it does. You would need to use `car === 2 || card === 3 || car === 4 || card === 5 || car === 6`. You cannot use the assignment operator `=` like this. You should use the [`strict comparison`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) operator instead.
It's even easier to use an array and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6].includes(card)`.

#### `count` is not updated

You need to assign the new value to `count` when you increment/ decrement it. You can use `count++` instead of `count + 1` which is the equivalent to `count = count + 1`.

```js
let count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if ([2, 3, 4, 5, 6].includes(card)) {
    count++;
  } else if ([10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"].includes(card)) {
    count--;
  }

  if (count > 0) return `${count} Bet`;
  return `${count} Hold`;
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```